# Hexadecimal file is loading with 2 back slashes before each byte instead of one

Tags: python, escaping, hex

I have a hex file in this format: `\xda\xd8\xb8\x7d`

When I load the file with Python, it loads with two back slashes instead of one.

```
with open('shellcode.txt', 'r') as file:
    shellcode = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Like this: `\\xda\\xd8\\xb8\\x7d`

I've tried using `hex.replace("\\", "\")`, but I'm getting an error

> EOL while scanning string literal

What is the proper way to replace `\\` with `\`?

Comment: Those are backslashes, not forward slashes.  The first one escapes the second one.  There isn't a problem.  Try printing the string

Comment: Use raw strings `hex.replace(r"\\", r"\")`  You escaped the final double-quote, hence the error.  However I'm dubious if the characters really look like this as a string, or this is just a string representation of the data.

Comment: How did you display the data?  Please show your code.  If `repr()` is used (which interactive python uses) the the extra `\ ` will be seen, but if `str()` is used (which `print` uses) then it will not be added.

Comment: @cdarke this hex is not used in the Python program.  I'm doing security work, and this hex is sent to another program to be executed as raw hex.

Comment: So how do you know there are two backslashes?  How is it being displayed?  Did you try raw strings?

Comment: Because I can see the hex dump while debugging the other program, and it's invalid hex with two back slashes.  I did try your raw string idea, but I still get the EOL error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
>>> h = "\\x123"
>>> h
'\\x123'
>>> print h
\x123
>>>
```

The two backslashes are needed because \ is an escape character, and so it needs to be escaped.  When you print h, it shows what you want

Answer (score 0):

Backshlash (`\`) is an escape character. It is used for changing the meaning of the character(s) following it.

For example, if you want to create a string which contains a quote, you have to escape it:

```
s = "abc\"def"
print s  # prints: abc"def
```

If there was no backslash, the first quote would be interpreted as the end of the string.

Now, if you really wanted that backslash in the string, you would have to escape the bacsklash using another backslash:

```
s = "abc\\def"
print s  # prints: abc\def
```

However, if you look at the representation of the string, it will be shown with the escape characters:

```
print repr(s)  # prints: 'abc\\def'
```

Therefore, this line should include escapes for each backslash:

```
hex.replace("\\", "\")  # wrong

hex.replace("\\\\", "\\")  # correct
```

But that is not the solution to the problem!

There is no way that `file.read().replace('\n', '')` introduced additional backslashes. What probably happened is that OP printed the representation of the string with backslashes (`\`) which ended up printing escaped backslashes (`\\`).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `bytes` object with a `utf-8` encoding, and then decode as `unicode-escape`.

```
>>> x = "\\x61\\x62\\x63"
>>> y = bytes(x, "utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")
>>> print(x)
\x61\x62\x63
>>> print(y)
abc
```